# Selenium Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException

Tags: java, selenium

I'm working on selenium using Firefor webdriver and getting the following exception when I create my webdriver instance.

```
WebDriver driver;
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

The strange thing that the code was running, and when I came to rerun it again, it gave me this exception

The exception message is:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException:        Could not start a new         session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser     start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:03:00'
System info: host: 'TOSHIBA', ip: '192.168.1.100', os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch:  'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.7.0_21'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:593)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:240)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:126)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
at Test.main(Test.java:68)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingInputStream.read(LoggingInputStream.java:87)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:136)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:152)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:270)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:161)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:153)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:254)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.fallBackExecute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:215)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:184)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.execute(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:165)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.execute(FirefoxDriver.java:362)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:572)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you positive the remote server is online and functioning?

Comment: Verify the version of your OS and chrome they should be same either 32x or 64x

Comment: I think yes. It was running well, but after few minutes it gave me these errors.

Comment: Can you start FireFox manually?

Comment: yes I can, I tried to uninstall it and install it again, but I got no result

Comment: One thing I can add to the problem, that I was running the project for long time and when it finished running, there was no driver.quit() at the end of the code, is it may be the reason of my problem? And how can I solve such problem then?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the latests version of selenium.
I have catched a similar exception few times, when get to selenium 4+ it disappeared.

Or maybe correct finishing of session will help:

```
webdriver.close(); // closes the browser or current page which is on focus
webdriver.quit();  // shutdown the web driver instance or destroy it's instance
```